# Tail recursive addition of Peano numbers in F# using accumulators

Tags: f#, peano-numbers

At Uni we were given a challenge of creating a tail recursive addition of Peano numbers using an accumulator. We aren't allowed to use any library function or other functions that we have created, but we are allowed to 'hide' the accumulator in an auxiliary function

Here's the type

```ml
  type Peano =
  | O
  | S of Peano
```

I'm stuck at how to execute the accumulator as it has no operation on the type defined, i.e. the following is not possible

```ml
  let tailAdd p1 p2 =
    let rec aux p1 p2 acc =
      match p1, p2 with
        | O, _   -> acc
        | S v, b -> aux v b (acc + v)

  aux p1 p2 O
```

Help xD

Comment: Forgot it, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```ml
let tailAdd p1 p2 = 
        let rec aux p1 p2 acc =
            match p1, p2 with
            | O, O   -> acc
            | a, S v -> aux v a (S (acc))
            | S v, b -> aux v b (S (acc))
        
        aux p1 p2 O
```

Comment: You can reduce duplication by combining the last two match cases.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to give away the answer, since this is a homework problem, but I'll give you a hint: In the case where `p1` matches with `S v`, you know that `v = p1 - 1`. Therefore, `p1 + p2 = v + (p2 + 1)`. So how do you write `p2 + 1` in Peano numbers?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, I came to that realisation yesterday and finally figured it out

Comment: Now that you've figured it out, I just wanted to mention that this problem doesn't actually require an accumulator, so I'm not sure why it was assigned with that requirement. There's a simpler solution using the same basic idea.